# How to constantly check the location of an object in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am working on a game that involves drawing lines to guide a physics ball into a bucket at the bottom of the screen. However, sometimes the user might draw the lines poorly, and the balls will become stuck. To rid this I would like to check the position of the balls every 3 seconds.

This is what I *thought* would work:

```
 function checkBallVelocity(event)
    startX = event.x
    startY = event.y

    timer.performWithDelay( 5000, function()

        endX = event.x
        endY = event.y

        print(startX..","..startY.." || "..endX..","..endY)
        if startX == endX or startY == endY then

            if event.other.name == "1" then

                circle1:removeSelf( )
                circle1 = nil

                ballsMissed = ballsMissed + 1
            elseif event.other.name == "2" then

                circle2:removeSelf( )
                circle2 = nil

                ballsMissed = ballsMissed + 1
            elseif event.other.name == "3" then

                circle3:removeSelf( )
                circle3 = nil

                ballsMissed = ballsMissed + 1
            end
            return 1
        else
            checkBallVelocity()
        end
    end
    )
end
```

Sadly, it doesn't. Any help/advice would be welcome

Comment: `event` is not available to the anonymous function.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Can you please elaborate what I should do to fix this? I thought I understood what you meant, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this sort of thing, but Corona provides an `enterFrame` event which fires each time a frame is drawn (30 or 60 frames per second). It can be used as a main loop to perform periodic actions, but keep in mind that it is run *quite* often so it helps to define a period and limit your actions to certain phases within the period.

```
local period
local phase = 0
function mainLoop(event) 
    phase = phase + 1
    if phase == 1 then 
       checkBallPosition(...)
    elseif phase == period
       phase = 0
    end
end
...
function scene:enterScene( event ) 
    period = display.fps * 3 -- # of seconds
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", mainLoop)
    ...
end
```